# Event Calender Notification Mail through PHP CURL

Tags: php, email, curl

I am trying to send the event calender to gmail/yahoo/outlook. For this i am using

```
            $from_name = "My Name";
            $from_address = "xxxxxx@example.com";
            $subject = "Meeting Booking"; //Doubles as email subject and meeting subject in calendar
            $meeting_description = "Here is a brief description of my meeting\n\n";
            $meeting_location = "My Office"; //Where will your meeting take place


            //Convert MYSQL datetime and construct iCal start, end and issue dates
            $meetingstamp = strtotime($meeting_date . " UTC");    
            $dtstart= gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z",$meetingstamp);
            $dtend= gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z",$meetingstamp+$meeting_duration);
            $todaystamp = gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z");

            //Create unique identifier
            $cal_uid = date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."-".rand()."@mydomain.com";

            //Create Mime Boundry
            $mime_boundary = "----Meeting Booking----".md5(time());

            //Create Email Headers
            $headers = array(
                    'From:'.$from_name.' <'.$from_address.'>\n',
                    'Reply-To: '.$from_name.' <'.$from_address.'>\n',
                    'MIME-Version: 1.0\n',
                    'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary='.$mime_boundary.'\n',
                    'Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\n'
            );
//            $headers = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
//            $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
//
//            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
//            $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\n";
//            $headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\n";

            //Create Email Body (HTML)
            $message .= "--$mime_boundary\n";
            $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
            $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";

            $message .= "<html>\n";
            $message .= "<body>\n";
            $message .= '<p>Dear '.$firstname.' '.$lastname.',</p>';
            $message .= '<p>Here is my HTML Email / Used for Meeting Description</p>';    
            $message .= "</body>\n";
            $message .= "</html>\n";
            $message .= "--$mime_boundary\n";

            //Create ICAL Content (Google rfc 2445 for details and examples of usage) 
            $ical =    'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
            PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
            VERSION:2.0
            METHOD:PUBLISH
            BEGIN:VEVENT
            ORGANIZER:MAILTO:'.$from_address.'
            DTSTART:'.$dtstart.'
            DTEND:'.$dtend.'
            LOCATION:'.$meeting_location.'
            TRANSP:OPAQUE
            SEQUENCE:0
            UID:'.$cal_uid.'
            DTSTAMP:'.$todaystamp.'
            DESCRIPTION:'.$meeting_description.'
            SUMMARY:'.$subject.'
            PRIORITY:5
            CLASS:PUBLIC
            END:VEVENT
            END:VCALENDAR';   

            $message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST;charset=utf-8\n';
            $message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST\n';
            $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
            $message .= $ical;      

            $mail_vars = array(
                'from_name' => $from_name,
                'from' => $from_address,
                'to' => $email,
                'subject' => $subject,
                'headers' => $headers,
                'body' => $message,
            );
            echo "<pre>";
            //print_r($mail_vars);
            echo "</pre>";
```

Note : I didn't mention the mail() function here
if I send this through simple mail() function, It is working fine. 
But, If I send the same mail using `CURL`, I am not getting the .ics file attachment and also the mail is not formatted. Simply, the mail looks like this

This is the CURL code

```
first way :                      

    $ch = curl_init($posturl);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$vars); 
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER ,1);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
                            $Rec_Data = curl_exec($ch);
second way :
                $ch = curl_init($posturl);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $mailparams['headers']);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpwd);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
                $Rec_Data = curl_exec($ch);
```

If I use the first way, I can able to send the mail, but that is not formatted.
In the second way, the mail is not going.

Please check and let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just learnt that sending emails using cURL is actually a thing.

Comment: Do you understand my question clearly.@timgws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I too tried to work with curl, but its not possible for me. So, I finally worked with the simple mail function. It is fast and easy. Go for it.

Answer (score 0):

`"[...] but that is not formatted [...]"` what do you mean by this? There is no formatting in the HTML that you are sending, so it is being sent correctly.

Could it be that `Content-Type: text/calendar` is there twice? Try getting rid of the first one (with `;charset=utf-8` in there) and see if that makes a difference.

Also, I can't see how it should make a difference, but try removing the spaces infront of the ical strings.

There is also  a mime boundary missing from the bottom of the email. What happens if you try to add that?

Comment: We can able to send the email with the same code using mail(), We are facing the problem only when we are passing the headers through the CURL. But, It is mandatory to pass the headers like this.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using cURL to send mail vs. using PHP's mail() function? Does mail() not work in your environment? Have you tried using the swiftmailer library instead of cURL?